# Is that the Steinberg representation of GL(n,F) is projective or injective ?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $F$ a non archimidian local field, $G$ the locally profinite group $GL(n,F)$, and 
$St_{G}$ the Steinberg representation of $G$. Is that the representation $St_{G}$ is projective or injective object in the category of smooth representations of $G$ ?

Notice that, a smooth representation $\pi$ of $G$ is supercuspidal if and only if it's projective and injective object in the category of smooth representations of $G$, then since $\mathbf{St}_{G}$ is not supercuspidal it is not projective and injective.

Answer (score 3):

Neither, for example for $n=2$ it has extensions with the trivial rep both ways. This is realized as $0\rightarrow 1\rightarrow Ind_B^G 1 \rightarrow St\rightarrow 0$, and taking the 
contragredient of this s.e.s. You could look at the ENS paper of Bernstein-Zelevenskii for more complicated examples.